# Which control has been clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem with MouseEvents on my WinForm C# application. I want to get ALL mouse clicks on my application.
How to determine which control has been clicked ?(I'm beginner C#)

Comment: What have you tried?  It depends on how the events are wired up.  The `sender` parameter of the event handler will tell you what object (control) sent the event but that may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: This is a pretty typical question for somebody that just got started on Winforms programming.  It is technically possible but Winforms makes it difficult on purpose.  It is just not the way it was designed to be used.  You are not supposed to care about *all* the clicks, just the ones that you want to give a meaning.  Which you do by writing the Click event handler for a control.  Make sure to at least follow a tutorial, a book is best.

Comment: +1 @HansPassant From a design perspective ask yourself - do you *really* want to handle every single mouse click? You're then stuck with figuring out how to handle it and passing it off to an appropriate method for action.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
private void Control_Clicks(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control control = (Control)sender;   // Sender gives you which control is clicked.
    MessageBox.Show(control.Name.ToString());
}
```

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457091.aspx), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530867/understanding-c-sharp-events-use-of-sender-object) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104674/why-should-events-in-c-sharp-take-sender-eventargs) may help.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Now this, this is the way.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetupClickEvents(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This will loop through each control within the container and add a click handler to it
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="container">The container whose children to handle clicks for</param>
    private void SetupClickEvents(Control container)
    {
        foreach(Control control in container.Controls)
        {
            control.Click += HandleClicks;
        }
    }
    private void HandleClicks(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = (Control)sender;
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} was clicked!", control.Name));
    }
```

Comment: The only drawback is that you have to loop through each control on the form. If you have many, many controls this could hurt performance. I just whipped up a quick form and gave it a test and it worked out as expected. You should be able to change this to do what you need (for example items within a specific container, etc)

Comment: The drawback is on startup, after that it should be good to go. My only comment about the above code is that it seems kind of redundant to wrap the handler in a lambda expression. I assume the compiler would realize this, but it's probably better just to attach the handler directly to the event.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, the lambda expression really isn't needed. I've updated the code to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: Also, you can skip the "new EventHandler" part too, but I'm sure that's purely syntactic sugar. :P

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing Windows Forms, you have several options :

1. [Hook mouse event](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx), and after figure out if the clicked component actually makes part of your application
2. You can declare a base class `MyComponent : Control`. That component overrides `MousClick` event and raise a [special event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c36axhcy.aspx) notifying about a fact. Every control in your app derive from that control, so every control will notify about click happened on it. It's enough to subcribe 
   to thier events and process them as requested.

Just a couple of ideas...

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to wire them all up to the same event handler. This can be done in the properties window for the controls in question. You could also write your own function to traverse the control tree and tie the function to each of their event handlers.

You can recursively traverse the Form.Controls collection with a foreach loop.

```
void attachGlobalHandler(Control aToParse, EventHandler aGlobalHandler)
{
    foreach(Control lControl in aToParse.Controls)
    {
        attachGlobalHandler(lControl, aGlobalHandler);
        lControl.Click += aGlobalHandler;
    }
}
```

And then you call that on your form, with the name of the function you want to call:

```
attachGlobalHandler( Form1, myClickHandler );
```

And that should tie it to EVERY clickable control on the form. The `sender` argument of the handler should then always refer to the control that fired the event. That being said, I'd probably just attach individual event handlers, unless you need to treat multiple controls as a group.

WARNING: The code above is untested.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question asked "How to determine which control has been clicked?" each control has events which may be handled in code.

The easiest way to know when a control has been clicked is to attached to the clicked event of a control which is done from the properties for the control.  You may have to click the lightning bolt icon to see the events.  Double-clicking beside the even will create an empty handler.

For example if you had a simple form with a single button attaching click events to the form and to the button will tell you when there is a click anywhere.  In most cases the button click would be the most useful to handle.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple!

On your click event in your Win-Form, You add

```
// Here is a modified version of your code:
private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var control = Form1.ActiveControl;
}
```