# How to modify the object (textBox) that called the method from within the method itself?

Tags: c#, object, methods, reference, sender

EDIT: This question has been solved using "sender" (see answer below)--thank you to everyone who left comments!

I'm trying to create a method that I can call within any number of text fields that will automatically check if the first char in the field is a period, and, if there isn't, to add a period (e.g. "exe" -> ".exe") whenever the user clicks away.

The actual text-check-and-change I got working, but I'm trying to figure out how to have the method automatically change *whichever* textBox called it. (That way, I'm not copying and pasting code and specifying the textBox name every time.)

The "this" is basically a placeholder at this point until I figure it out:

```
        // making sure the first char in the text box always has a . for the extension
        public void periodFix()
        {
            this.Text = this.Text.Trim();
            if (this.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                char[] textBoxContents = this.Text.ToCharArray();
                if (textBoxContents[0] != '.')
                {
                    string tempString = "." + this.Text;
                    this.Text = tempString;

                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.Text = ".";
            }
        }
```

```
        private void textBox7_Leave_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            periodFix();
        }
```

I feel like there has to be a way to do this, but I'm still learning C# and my vocab to identify specifically what it is I'm trying to do is lacking.

In the code above, I tried using "this", which hasn't worked.

I tried using "sender" in the place of "this" which didn't work.

I also tried passing in by reference (ref this, ref textBox, etc.) and none of the syntax seemed to be working right.

Comment: Well, `sender` should be the droid you are looking for.  You might want to explain how it "didnt work" and pose the question from the angle of identifying the "problem".  (As per the argument types, the caller is passed as object, so you need to cast it to access TextBox` properties

Comment: See if this helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530867/understanding-c-sharp-events-use-of-sender-object

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp Thank you! I finally figured out the problem; the method just wasn't understanding the TextBox control.

Comment: @hallibut Thank you! This got me in the right place. sender was what I needed; my reference to the object type just wasn't specific enough.

Comment: Are all of the textboxes on the same window (form)? If so, you can use just one event handler for all of them, and use `sender` to apply your code to the current one being exited.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to Ňɏssa and hallibut in the comments. I thought there was a fundamental problem with using sender, but the issue was that Windows needed the full path for the TextBox's object type and I was overthinking the problem.

Here's the corrected code that worked:

```
private void periodFix(object sender)
{
    // making sure the first char in the text box always has a . for the extension
    System.Windows.Forms.TextBox tb = System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)sender;
    tb.Text = tb.Text.Trim();
    if (tb.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        char[] textBoxContents = tb.Text.ToCharArray();
        if (textBoxContents[0] != '.')
        {
            string tempString = "." + tb.Text;
            tb.Text = tempString;
         }
     }
     else
     {
         tb.Text = ".";
     }
}

private void textBox7_Leave_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // making sure the first char in the text box always has a . for the extension
    periodFix(sender);
}
```